# Generation of an array of Random numbers with defined Min, Max, Mean and Stdev with given number of elements and error level

Tags: c++, python, statistics, generator

I'd like to generate an array of Random numbers with defined Min, Max, Mean and Stdev with given number of elements and error level. Is there such a library in C, C++, PHP or Python to do so? Please kindly advise. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean an array of random numbers?

Comment: A random array or "just an array"?

Comment: Random numbers that satisfy the given constraints: Min, Max, Mean, Stdev, error level and defined number of elements.

Comment: I lost 2 votes. That's too harsh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Boost C++ random number library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/random/index.html) may do some of what you want, certainly you can with some distributions select the modal value of the distribution. That's all I've needed in my own code, so I've never investigated further. The library doesn't generate arrays - you would typically use  a C++ `std::vector` to contain the results of random number generation.

Comment: @Vliet If you are interested in generating random data (not just numbers) you might want to take a look at my FOSS project at http://code.google.com/p/csvtest, though it doesn't do what your question asks about.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use python, then I suggest that you use numpy.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.random.html

You can probably find many distributions that fit your needs, but maybe you can sample from a beta distribution and rescale the values to fit your needs. Your code will end up looking like this

```
a1, a2 = ....
temp_array = numpy.random.beta(a1, a2, array_size)
answer = temp_array*(max_value-min_value) + min_value
```

If you choose this aproach then you need to do a bit of work to find formulas for a1 and a2.